# Tensorflow: add a scalar_summary to SummaryWriter without session.run()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I was wondering whether the is a direct way to add a scalar_summary to SummaryWriter without using session.run() to get the summaries.

Usually the code for getting and adding a summary is:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("./logs", sess.graph)
    merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    summary, acc = sess.run([merged, acc_op], feed_dict)
    writer.add_summary(summary, current_step) #Save summary at some checkpoint step
```

However, I simply want to plot the accuracy values and loss values, which were retrieved AND PROCESSED AFTER training, as line graphs on tensorboard:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("./logs", sess.graph)
    acc, loss = sess.run([acc_op, loss_op], feed_dict) #Only the get accuracy and loss
    acc = acc*100

    tf.scalar_summary('accuracy', acc)
    tf.scalar_summary('loss', loss)

    merged = tf.merge_all_summaries() #Merge all the summaries into one
    writer.add_summary(merged, current_step) #Save summary at some checkpoint step
```

The code above will print out this error:

```
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected Summary got Tensor. for field Event.summary
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the summary writer to write a series values of acc_op and loss_op to disk, which the tensorboard read from.

Or you can store the values of acc_op and loss_op to an array and plot them after training is done.